# Confirm Form Resubmission issue in my website

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, web

Good day, guys! I'm currently developing a website and the problem is when I refresh the page it will prompt a confirm form resubmission. How can I solve this issue? thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume that you initially submit a form, then refresh the page to encounter this problem? If so, after form submission the first time use a `header('location: /index.php' )` etc

Comment: Thank you.  This is a big help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of HTML form validation!

The most common solution to this problem is, once the form data has been validated and processed, issue a header command to show the confirmation page.

```
if($bDataOK){
    header('Location: http://example.com/page_ok_message.php');
    exit;
}
else{
    //Show the current form again with error messages
}
```

Put this near the top of you PHP before other output is sent, otherwise you'll get error messages about sending headers too late.

Comment: I will try this code then I will accept this answer thank you.